# JavaScript incorrectly converting milliseconds to date?

Tags: javascript, date

I've noticed an issue with some data I'm processing (2000+ lines of data).

The problem is very strange: the code works fine! *UNTIL* a specific date is reached (in this case 01/08/2011) when JavaScript fails to generate the correct date?

So, to explain: I'm taking a string in the format of 'dd/mm/yyyy' and doing (which doesn't work):

- `var date = '01/08/2011'.split('/');`
- `var milliseconds = new Date(date[2], parseInt(date[1]) - 1, date[0]).getTime();` => 1291161600000
- `new Date(1291161600000);` => Wed Dec 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

...but yet that exact code works fine with any date before the 1st August 2011?

So try again with `29/07/2011`...

- `var date = '29/07/2011'.split('/');`
- `var milliseconds = new Date(date[2], parseInt(date[1]) - 1, date[0]).getTime();` => 1311894000000
- `new Date(1311894000000);` => Fri Jul 29 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

The only difference is the (GMT) and (BST) values returned, which suggests a locale issue. But why would that occur, and how can I fix the code to work around that?

Many thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: `parseInt('08') == 0`, but `parseInt('08', 10) == 8`

Comment: datejs ( http://www.datejs.com/ ) is an outstanding culture aware open source JavaScript date library. See the Date.parse method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing octal!

Use a radix!

```
parseInt(date[1],10)
```

From the [MDN Docs `parseInt(string[, radix])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If radix is undefined or 0, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16 (hexadecimal).
> - If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal). This feature is non-standard, and some implementations deliberately do not
>     support it (instead using the radix 10). For this reason always
>     specify a radix when using parseInt.
> - If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).